# How to get a valid HttpContextBase inside of a Task

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

The following code will throw an exception when accessing the corresponding url.  Object `state` in `StartNew()` is not the same as `ctx` in `ProcessRequest`.  Why is this happening?  How can I get a valid `HttpContextBase` object in side of `StartNew()`?

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace AsyncUseHttpContextBaseWillFail
{
    public class FooHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var ctx = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(state =>
            {
                //ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
                var ip = ((HttpContextBase)state).Request.UserHostAddress;
            }, ctx);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }

    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.Add(new Route(string.Empty, new FooRoute()));
        }
    }

    public class FooRoute : IRouteHandler
    {
        public virtual IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext context)
        {
            return new FooHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Could you use an IAsyncHttpHandler instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Could you post the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Steve's comment above is your best bet for making this work correctly.  Use IHttpAsyncHandler or HttpTaskAsyncHandler.  Even if you do manage to pass a valid HttpContext[Base] into your callback, if ProcessRequest has already returned then the ASP.NET runtime could have cleaned up the HttpContext instance, and you will be trying to work with a disposed object.  Asynchronous work should always be performed by an asynchronous handler so as to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the required data out of the `HttpContext` to local variables and use these variables in your lambda. Accessing the `HttpContext` from a second thread is not safe.